# Alert dialog with custom list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I want to create an alert dialog with  custom list view. For this I have created custom layout and adapter for list view.
I want the alert dialog with single choice Items. So I have set an adapter to the dialog. Now I want to get the selected item from array list?

```
  selectTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final TimeTable table = new TimeTable();

                List<TimeTable> allTables = new ArrayList<TimeTable>();

                TimeTableHelper timeTableHelper = new TimeTableHelper(AddEventActivity.this);

                allTables = timeTableHelper.getAllTables();



                allTables.add(table);

                final List<TimeTable> t = th.getAllTables();
                for (TimeTable cn : allTables) {
                    String log = "Id: " + cn.getId() + " ,Title: " + cn.getTitle() +
                            "Status: " + cn.getStatus() + ",Color: " + cn.getTableColor();

                    Log.d("Data ", log);
                }
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEventActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablelist, null, false);

                lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableslist);

                final CustomAlertAdapter adapter = new CustomAlertAdapter(allTables, AddEventActivity.this);


                alertDialog.setView(convertView);

                                   alertDialog.setView(customView);

               alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                       final List<TimeTable> tables = new ArrayList<TimeTable>();

                       // what to do here to get item of TimeTable list?
                   }
               });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

EDIT:

```
           alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, selected, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {


                   TimeTable selectedItem = allTables.get(which);

                   selectedItem.getId();
                   txtTable.setText(selectedItem.getTitle());
                   Log.d("TableId", String.valueOf(selectedItem));

                   dialog.dismiss();

               }
           });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

customAlertAdapter

```
public class CustomAlertAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


        List<TimeTable> mData;
        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        public CustomAlertAdapter(List<TimeTable> data, Context context) {
            mData = data;
            mContext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null ) {

                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);

            }

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableTitle);
            Button color = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectColor);


            tvTitle.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());

            ((GradientDrawable)color.getBackground()).setColor(mData.get(position).getTableColor());

            return convertView;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `which` parameter indicates the index of selected item. So you can write:

```
TimeTable selectedItem = allTables.get(which);
```

In addition, I think when you call `setSingleChoiceItem` method, there is no need to provide custom view for dialog.

Here is a working sample with string array:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Dialog").setSingleChoiceItems(new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2"}, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            //Item 1 was selected
                            break;
                        case 1:
                           //Item 2 was selected
                            break;
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create();
dialog.show();
```

You can pas `ListAdapter` instead of String array.

Comment: Item is not getting clicked. nothing happens if i click on item.

Comment: @Sid try to remove custom view from alert dialog.

Comment: If i directly add array list it shows error it dose not resolve the listener

Comment: That's what i have done please check edited question. but nothing is happening on click. i tried adding .create() as your code.

Comment: Try the string array sample just for test and if it works correctly maybe the problem is in your adapter. Does your rows in adapter have any clickable component such as button or checkbox?

Comment: it's working with string array. I don't get what's wrong. please check adapter i am adding in question.

Comment: I have added button to show color. Is it a problem?

Comment: @Sid, as an experiment, before removing button you can set its `focusable` attribute to `false` in xml layout file. Maybe it can fix the problem.

Comment: sure will try it too.. Thank you.. @Misagh Emamverdi